# How can I restore Java on my mac

Tags: java, mysql, macos, aptana

I had aptana and xampp on my mac, and when tried to download eclipse, it required me to download, as I recall, jdk 7.0... I ran a shell command that I found online, and after I did, Eclipse worked, but Aptana and xampp's MySQL database both stopped working... I tried to download jre 1.8, tried this link (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202643)  to restore mac's original java jre and tried to redownload aptana but all did not solve the issue.

This is the message am getting from Aptana:
The JVM shared library "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/../jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib" does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol.

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found solution, just download this: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

as for xampp, I copied/back-uped everything in htdocs and reinstalled it... now mysql works but apache web server does not :(